# jQuery .done() not firing on $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I have the following sentence:

```
var token = 'token';

$.post("/signup.php", {token: token}).done(function(data) {
    alert("done");
});
```

This actually doesn't works, and I honestly don't know why, because it's so simply... I have jQuery 1.11.1, and "signup.php" takes up to 10 seconds to be completed and return a success answer. It's possible it's not working due the time signup.php takes to be processed?

Thank you guys

Comment: Add `.fail()` as well and you will probably see an error is occurring. At least then you can display the details of the error (timeout etc)

Comment: Any error in the Javascript console?

Comment: No, it just returns an URL... and this is correct because it means it's doing al process correctly

Answer (score 0):

try adding timeout attribute, since the result is taking too much time. Also,
I feel that token should be in headers attribute.

```
$.post("/signup.php", {headers: {token: token}, timeout : 20000}).done(function(data) {
    alert("done");
});
```